# Print all possible chess knight moves - JS

Tags: javascript

I have a form with chess Knight position input value (ex. D4). After clicking "Show", the system should show all possible moves (coordinates) from defined position (ex. C2 E2 F3 F5 E6 C6 B3 B5).

```js
let form = document.getElementById("chessKnight")
let btn = document.getElementById("button")
btn.addEventListener("click", chessKnight)

function chessKnight(cell) {
  var possibleCoordinates = [];
  var xCoordinates = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
  var cellX = xCoordinates.indexOf(cell[0]) + 1;
  var cellY = parseInt(cell[1]);

  var cellXpositions = [cellX + 2, cellX - 2, cellX + 1, cellX -
    1
  ].filter(function(cellPosition) {
    return (cellPosition > 0 && cellPosition < 9);
  })

  var cellYpositions = [cellY + 2, cellY - 2, cellY + 1, cellY -
    1
  ].filter(function(cellPosition) {
    return (cellPosition > 0 && cellPosition < 9);
  })

  for (var i = 0; i < cellXpositions.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cellYpositions.length; j++) {
      if (!possibleCoordinates.includes([cellXpositions[i],
          cellYpositions[j]
        ])) {
        possibleCoordinates.push([cellXpositions[i],
          cellYpositions[j]
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('Possible Coordinates:', possibleCoordinates);
  return possibleCoordinates.length;
}
```

```html
<input id="chessKnight" type="text">
<button id="button">Show</button>
```

The system shows the following: 'Possible Coordinates:' []

Comment: `TypeError: cell is undefined`. Just run your own snippet and you have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a coordinate system where a position is represented by a single integer: 3 bits for the row, 3 bits for the column, each preceded by 1 bit to detect over/underflow. So a position is encoded with 8 bits.

It allows for short code:

```js
function chessKnight(pos) {
  pos = pos[1]-1 + ("ABCDEFGH".indexOf(pos[0].toUpperCase()) << 4); // Convert

  return [-0x12, -0x21, -0x1F, -0x0E, 0x12, 0x21, 0x1F, 0x0E] // All relative moves
      .map(i => pos+i) // Add to current position
      .filter(i => !(i & 0x88)) // Detect under/overflow, i.e. off-the-board
      .map(i => "ABCDEFGH"[i>>4] + ((i & 7)+1)); // Convert to output format
}

// I/O handling:
const knight = document.getElementById("chessKnight");
const btn = document.getElementById("button");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const moves = chessKnight(knight.value);
    output.textContent = `${moves.length} possible moves: ${moves}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="chessKnight" type="text">
<button id="button">Show</button>
<div id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `cell` to the function, otherwise the script can't read properties of the cell

```
// your button calls the function without passing the cell
chessKnight() 

// but the function expects a cell
function chessKnight(cell) {
   console.log(cell)
}
```

You might fix it by reading the value of the form

HTML

```
<input id="chessKnight" type="text">
<button id="button">Show</button>
```

JS

```
let form = document.getElementById("chessKnight")
let btn = document.getElementById("button")
btn.addEventListener("click", chessKnight)

function chessKnight() {
   var cell = form.value
   console.log(cell)
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've added a function that gets the rows and columns from the input field. This works by using `fromCharCode` and `charCodeAt` to convert a letter to a number, and vice versa.

Once you have the rows and columns as numbers, you can do your calculations. When you're finished calculating, convert the number back to a letter again.

In this solution I have an array of possible knight moves (always 8 moves for a knight), but you could solve this with a math function as well.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("chessKnight")
let knightBtn = document.getElementById("button")
let result = document.getElementById("result")
knightBtn.addEventListener("click", showPossibleMoves)


function showPossibleMoves() {
  let cell = form.value
  // convert letter to number
  let x = parseInt(cell.substring(0,1).charCodeAt() - 64)
  let y = parseInt(cell.substring(1,2))
  
  let knightMoves = [
    {x:2, y:-1},{x:2, y:1},{x:1, y:-2},{x:1, y:2},
    {x:-2, y:-1},{x:-2, y:1},{x:-1, y:-2},{x:-1, y:2}
  ]
  
  let possibleMoves = []
  for(let m of knightMoves) {
    let row = String.fromCharCode(x + m.x + 64)
    let column = y+m.y
    possibleMoves.push(row + "" + column)
  }
  console.log('Possible Coordinates:', possibleMoves);
  result.innerHTML = possibleMoves.toString()
}
```

```html
<input id="chessKnight" type="text" value="D4">
<button id="button">Knight Moves</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited the code as per your advice, and now no errors are shown, however, no output is seen either..

Comment: Well, that's because `C4` in the form field is just a string, so you can't use `cell[0]` and `cell[1]` to separate the C and the 4 from `C4`. Instead, you could use `cell.substring(0,1)` and `cell.substring(1,2)` to get those values.